# Input arrays not inserting into database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to insert inputs from a clone form into the database using ajax. When I click on submit button it kept on saying 'Data Inserted' but it actually don't get to the database.

Here is the html

```
<div class="modal fade" id="skills_dialog" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span> Add Skills</h4>
            </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                 <form id="skill_form"  method="post" action="skill/add.php">
                <div class="textbox-wrapper">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" name="skills[]" class="form-control"  style="margin-bottom:7px;"/>
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success add-textbox"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" id="addSkills" class="btn btn-default">Add</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

for the jquery part of it

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var max = 10;
        var cnt = 1;
        $(".add-textbox").on("click", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            if(cnt < max){
                cnt++;
                $(".textbox-wrapper").append('<div class="input-group"><input type="text" name="skills[]" class="form-control" style="margin-bottom:7px;"/><span class="input-group-btn"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-textbox"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></button></span></div>');
            }
        });

        $(".textbox-wrapper").on("click",".remove-textbox", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parents(".input-group").remove();
            cnt--;
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Jquery that processes the skills inputs

```
<script>
/* must apply only after HTML has loaded */
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#skill_form").on("submit", function(e) {
        var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
        var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
        $.ajax({
            url: formURL,
            type: "POST",
            data: postData,
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $('#skills_dialog .modal-header .modal-title').html("Result");
                $('#skills_dialog .modal-body').html(data);
                $("#addSkills").remove();
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
                console.log(status + ": " + error);
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $("#addSkills").on('click', function() {
        $("#skill_form").submit();
    });
});
</script>



<script>
$('textarea.expand').focus(function () {
    $(this).animate({ height: "4em" }, 500); 
});
</script>
```

and lastly, the insert query

```
<?php 
session_start();
$user = $_SESSION['user_name']; 
error_reporting(0);
include('includes/db.php');
if($_POST){

    $number = count($_POST["skills"]);  
 if($number > 0)  
 {  
      for($i=0; $i<$number; $i++)  
      {  
           if(trim($_POST["skills"][$i] != ''))  
           {  
                $sql = "INSERT INTO skills(user, skills) VALUES('$user','".$_POST["skills"][$i]."')";  
                mysql_query($sql);  
           }  
      }  
      echo "Data Inserted";  
 }  
 else  
 {  
      echo "Please Enter Skill(s)";  
 }  
 }

?>
```

Comment: Where is your ajax call? Also you are going to get so many flags for that `INSERT`

Comment: Where is your submit button in yoir html ?

Comment: You echo "Data Inserted" whether the query works or not. By the way, you're using an outdated database extension, and your query is open to SQL injection.

Comment: There is no call to the PHP file. you are not submitting any data.

Comment: @Rabin, just add the jquery now - thought I did add it.

Comment: @SK Jajoriya, you can find that in the modal box.

Comment: @Lixux, Just add the ajax call now.

Comment: You misplaced a closing ) where your `trim` function is just above the SQL command